# showing Tenant app on mobile device pin list

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a power app and then created a custom app within teams using app studio manifest editor. I would like to know how I can now pin this app to the pin bar at the side on the desktop client and on the bottom on a mobile client.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Comer Here is how you could pre pin your custom app on the pin bar-[App-prepinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies).